# SIGIO isn't POSIX and SIGPOLL is marked "Obsolescent". What do I use?

Tags: signals, posix

I'm learning about signals in C. I'm trying to write a program that complies with POSIX and ANSI standards.  I want my program to be signaled when something happens but SIGIO isn't POSIX and SIGPOLL is marked as "Obsolescent" in [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

What signal do I use in my program?

Answer (score 0):

What about `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`?

> The SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals are set aside for you to use any way you want. They’re useful for simple interprocess communication, if you write a signal handler for them in the program that receives the signal.

[Miscellaneous Signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html)

Comment: How would I get `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` to fire any time a socket has activity?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean now, as far as sockets are concerned. Great question! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I assume that you are just curious about it and not having some issue because of it?

Comment: It's just curiosity, yeah. Every major OS seems to support SIGIO, but SIGIO isn't part of the POSIX standard, so it's not "guaranteed". I've been challenging myself to write software that is 100% POSIX compliant as a way to learn about such things (and improve portability of my code), and I noticed this odd detail that seems to have simply slipped through the cracks.